# EditText Drawable Right not working when upgrading design support library

Tags: android

I have upgraded support library from 'com.android.support:design:23.0.0' to 'com.android.support:design:25.0.0'. Now drawableright(Image) not working for EditText. Here is my code.

```
 <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <EditText
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_calendar"/>


                </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

update your support library

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
```

Answer (score 1):

Add drawableEnd to your edittext this way

```
<EditText
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_calendar"
                    android:drawableEnd="@drawable/ic_calendar"/>
```

Comment: if it helps then approve my answer